# Parsing json Inner Array -java

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is my json response :

```
{    
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Perkinston, MS, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Sunnyvale, CA, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "3,586 km",
                  "value" : 3585861
                            },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 day 8 hours",
                  "value" : 115992
                            },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

What I want is, to add `"text" : "3,586 km"` in a list after parsing .
What i Have tried is :

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");
System.out.println("size:"+array.length());
for(i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
JSONObject objects = new JSONObject(array.getJSONObject(i));
JSONArray element = objects.getJSONArray("elements");
JSONObject distance = new JSONObject(element.getJSONObject(i));
list.add(element.getJSONObject("").getString("text"));
```

What Error I am getting is : `Object["elements"] not found`

Help pls !

Comment: Format it. See "help" and make it readable.

Comment: I guess formatting is not that bad , Its pretty understandable .

Comment: -1 - Question looks like a dogs breakfast.  If you can't be bothered to format it, I can't be bothered to read it.

Comment: Try using JSon parser GSon by google it is much easier than parsing with JsonObjects.

Comment: What json parser do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `for` loop which iterates over the `array` object to something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject objects = array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray elements = objects.getJSONArray("elements");
    for (int j = 0; j < elements.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject element = elements.getJSONObject(i);
        list.add(element.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text"));
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Since your `elements` is an array as well, you'll need a `loop` to iterate over that. And your required text is present in the `distance` object.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Here，why are you do this:

    JSONObject objects = new JSONObject(array.getJSONObject(i));

    why not :

    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
```

and [here is an article](http://eagletony.iteye.com/blog/845152) that may be helpfull for you

Comment: I am not sure ,case i am not use the lib,but use gson.But you can try,it's easy.

Comment: This could have been a comment! I don't see this as an answer at all!

Comment: i have given you an article,can't you see it?